# select dropdown option based on dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery

To be honest, I have never touched Javascript before today. On basic search I have seen a few scripts use the change function but the samples seem very specific (using `.indexOf` and changing numbers/text boxes doesn't apply here).

removed

You can ignore the code that's there. essentially what I'm looking for is when 1 (disease) becomes yes, 6 option is changed to patient, and if 6 (poster_type) value = patient then 7 is selected as yes.

If someone could walk me through the change function that'd be fine too.

removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code and explanation below

So, the code says whenever disease dropdown is changed 
      if its selected value is "1"
          change the poster_type dropdown to Patient.
          change the patient_exp dropdown to "1" 
      else 
          change the poster_type dropdown to Unknown.
          change the patient_exp dropdown to "0"

```
   $("select[name='disease']").change(function(){
      if($("select[name='disease']").val() == "1"){
          $("select[name='poster_type']").val("Patient");
          $("select[name='patient_exp']").val("1");
      }
      else 
      {
          $("select[name='poster_type']").val("Unknown");
          $("select[name='patient_exp']").val("0");
      }
    });
```

For change in value of poster_type dropdown,
      if current selected value in poster_type is Patient
          set value of patient_exp dropdown to "1"
      else 
          set value of patient_exp dropdown to "0"

```
$("select[name='poster_type']").change(function(){

      if($("select[name='poster_type']").val() == "Patient")
          {
             $("select[name='patient_exp']").val("1");
          }
          else 
          {
             $("select[name='patient_exp']").val("0");
           }
       });
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to bind to the change event:

```
$('select[name=disease]').on('change', function(e){
    // here the user have changed the value
});
```

Then you can get current value with val():

```
$('select[name=disease]').val();
// yes or no
```

Val is also the method you use to change an input value:

```
$('input[name=myInput]').val('newVal');
```

So you're looking for something like this:

```
$('select[name=disease]').on('change', function(e){
    if($('select[name=disease]').val() === 'yes'){
        $('input[name=myInput]').val('my-new-value');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for walking through the change code. It helps a lot! :)